# Delete files from all subdirectories keeping folder structure except for one subdirectory

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to remove all files from all subdirectories, while keep the structure of the folders, but excluding the removal of files from the month of October 2019 in each subdirectory ⇒ `root_dir\*\2019\October\`

The directory structure looks like this:

```
C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder
├───Directory1
│   ├───2018
│   │   ├───April
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───August
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───February
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───January
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───July
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───June
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───March
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───May
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   ├───October
│   │   │   └───Error
│   │   └───September
│   │       └───Error
│   └───2019
│       ├───April
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───August
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───February
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───January
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───July
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───June
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───March
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───May
│       │   └───Error
│       ├───October
│       │   └───Error
│       └───September
│           └───Error
└───Directory2
    ├───2018
    │   ├───April
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───August
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───February
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───January
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───July
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───June
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───March
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───May
    │   │   └───Error
    │   ├───October
    │   │   └───Error
    │   └───September
    │       └───Error
    └───2019
        ├───April
        │   └───Error
        ├───August
        │   └───Error
        ├───February
        │   └───Error
        ├───January
        │   └───Error
        ├───July
        │   └───Error
        ├───June
        │   └───Error
        ├───March
        │   └───Error
        ├───May
        │   └───Error
        ├───October
        │   └───Error
        └───September
            └───Error
```

From Microsoft PowerShell docs I should be able to wildcard the exclude path. I've tried a few variations but here is where I'm currently at:

```cs
$root     = 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder'
$excludes = 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder\*\2019\October\'

Get-ChildItem $root -Directory -Exclude $excludes | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -File -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Force
}
```

The above works except its still removing files from `C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder\Directory1\2019\October\*` and `C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder\Directory2\2019\October\*`

I've tried specifying `.\2019\October\*.*` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest a different approach:

```
$root     = 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder'
$excludes = '*\2019\October\*'

Get-ChildItem $root -File -Recurse |
  Where-Object FullName -notlike $excludes |
    Remove-Item -Force -WhatIf
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the removal operation; remove it to perform actual removal.</sup>

For simplicity, *all* files in the subtree are enumerated, and then filtered out by whether their full paths contain `\2019\October\` path components.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `$excludes = 'C:\Users\User1\Documents\MyFolder\*\2019\October\'`

The `-Exclude` parameter only supports file *name* patterns, not full *paths* - though there is a pending [feature request on GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4126) to add support for paths.

Also, using `Get-ChildItem -Exclude` *without `-Recurse`* doesn't work the way one would expect: the exclusion is then applied to the *input path* only - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3304).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I was unaware of `-WhatIf` so that will definitely be useful for future reference.

Comment: @Gorgon_Union: Glad to hear it was helpful; yes, `-WhatIf` is a good tool to have on your belt, though not all cmdlets support it (those that don't, error out). `-WhatIf` is one instance of a [common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters).